# I don't see the difference export makes in BASH

Tags: bash, terminal

In my .bash_profile, I added a new path into $PATH and exported it so that I am able to run scripts in that directory.

However, when I removed the word "export", reopened the terminal and launched a new shell, I was still able to run those scripts.

I do understand that export makes a variable visible to subprocesses, but as you can see, here it does not really make a difference.

Can someone explain to me why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the PATH in your new shell? env | grep PATH

Comment: yes I did. the added path is there, and that's what confused me

Comment: .bash_profile will be run (sourced in) on login shell and .bashrc is for every new shell. most likely you need to reboot to get rid of the old bash_profile effect. use .bashrc instead.

Answer (score 3):

`.bash_profile` is sourced into the shell. As such, the variables do not need to be exported for use in the shell. However, if you run a non-shell (e.g. C or Python) program that uses `exec*p*(3)` then they won't have access to the new value of `$PATH` and may fail.

Comment: Oh ok. Does Mac terminal always do that (source .bash_profile into the new shell)?

Comment: Not the terminal will source that, but every newly started shell (and a terminal typically starts a shell to run in it).  Have a look at the chapter "INVOCATION" in the manpage of the `bash` to find out which files are used in which case.

Comment: It's probably also worth pointing out that `PATH` is likely to be exported much earlier than the user's own `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, so just removing the `export` keyword from the user's file isn't really a valid experiment. `export -n PATH` would force it to be *unexported*, so would be a better way to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: The first file `bash` sources is `/etc/profile`, which on a Mac runs calls `eval` on the output of `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which outputs valid code to set `PATH` based on the contents of `/etc/paths.d/` and exports `PATH`.